# ui:repeat did not actualize inside element(p:spinner), after change in BackingBean

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

My xhtml

```
#{seating.cntPLayersInRow} <!--This looks great, is same like in BackingBean-->
<h:form>
   <ui:repeat value="#{seating.cntPLayersInRow}" var="cntInRow" >
        <p:spinner value="#{cntInRow}"  > <!--Here is the Problem the value never  actualize -->    
       </p:spinner>
   </ui:repeat>
   <h:commandButton value="přidat řadu" action="#{seating.addRow()}" />
</h:form>
```

My method addRow in backingBean:

```
public String addRow() { //I Think not very import just change all value and add one
        cntRow++;
        cntPLayersInRow.clear(); 
        for (int i = 1; i < cntRow; i++) {
            cntPLayersInRow.add(someNumber/cntRow);            
        }             
        cntPLayersInRow.add(someNumber/cntRow+someNumber%cntRow);       
        return null;
}
```

cntPlayersInRow is ArrayList of Integers

Problem is that the value in p:spinner is not actualize when the cntPlayerInRow is actualized in BackinBean(scope is ViewScope)

Sorry for my English.

Comment: You might need to post the rest of your backing bean code. At what point is `addRow()` called? Are you saying that your code, as-is, used to work?

Comment: I think that the problem is same like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8280168/dynamically-added-input-field-in-uirepeat-is-not-processed-during-form-submit